# Proxy aspx page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have to create an aspx page that behind the scene will create a http request to another aspx page that's on a different domain and will return this content back to the user.

Is it good if I make an http web request in the 'PAGE_LOAD' event and then continue with: Response.Clear() to clear page default response and then Response.Write() where I will write the response from the http web request to the crossdomain page ?

I'm looking to know if this is a good way of replacing the initial response body.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this will work. Remember to have `Response.End()` when you are done.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla - It seems that the Response.End() throws an ex to abort the current thread and this makes me wonder if there are any other alternatives to avoid performance penalties. What if I don't abort the thread and let it finish, wouldn't be better this way ?

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla, this is normal behavior if one calls Response.End():
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Yes, an exception there is ok.